# Powershell Recursive Copy Except Files found in Exclusion directory

Tags: powershell

Hi I have a folder Called "A" and folder "A" has files and sub folders within it. I also have another folder directory called "Exclusion" with some copied files and folders from "A" within it. I'm looking for a Powershell script or Command Line option that will COPY & MOVE all the objects from A that are NOT found in the Exclusion directory to a new folder directory called "Output".

Thanks, 
-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to get a list of files in your exclusion directory, then take only the names of the files and hold those in an array.

Optionally use `New-Item` with the `-Force` parameter to ensure that your output directory exists before sending files there.

Next use `Get-ChildItem` to iterate through all files in our source (A) directory, use `Where-Object` and the `-notin` operator to exclude any files which have the same names as those gathered from your exclusion directory, then use `Move-Item` to move the files to your destination (Output) directory.

```
[string[]]$filenamesToExclude = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\somewhere\exclusion' -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
New-Item -Path 'c:\somewhere\output\' -ItemType 'Directory' -Force | Out-Null #ensure the target directory exists / don't output this command's return value to the pipeline
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\somewhere\A' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $filenamesToExclude} | Move-Item -Destination 'c:\somewhere\output\'
```

Comment: Hi John, I was testing it out locally just now. Thanks for the quick response. The code looks great and is very informative.